# Configure Error on iostream

Tags: iostream, mpich, icc

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and tried to compile MPICH from the source using Intel Compilers 2013. I use this command to configure mpich:

```
./configure CC=icc CXX=icpc F77=ifort FC=ifort -prefix=/home/user/mpich-install
```

and I get this error after a while:

```
.
.
checking whether <iostream> available... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... icpc -E
checking iostream.h usability... no
checking iostream.h presence... no
checking for iostream.h... no
configure: error: C++ compiler icpc   has neither iostream nor iostream.h.
configure: error: ./configure failed for test/mpi
```

Comment: Q: Rather than try to debug why the "configure" script doesn't work with "Intel Compilers 2013", why not just `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and use gcc/g++ to build your package?

Comment: @FoggyDay: I already did and it worked fine. This is a related issue which in Intel C++ compiler. check this link for more information: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/531138#comment-1799768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a known issue in Intel C++ compiler 14 update 1. It can be solved by updating to ICC 14 update 2. check this link for more information:

[software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/531138#comment-1799768](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/531138#comment-1799768)